# If you don't give up your life, are you liable?

Tags: halacha, death

The Gemarah in Sanhedrin says that there are three things a person should give up his life for rather than violate. They are idolatry, murder and sexual immorality. But suppose, if a guy has a gun to your head, and says, "Worship my God or I'll kill you" and you can't muster up the courage to be killed, are you in violation of the Halacha to Martyr yourself? Or does the commandment of Vchai Bahem take over and therefore you are not in any violation?

Comment: If you worshiped his god (lowercase), you would be liable for Karet (spiritual excision).

Comment: Why might you think you wouldn't be in violation?

Comment: I think that the question could be made stronger. Basically, as written, it asks, "There is a law to become a martyr for certain things; if you don't fulfill that law, have you violated it?" I have to support @DoubleAA's comment, even though I would like to see answers to this question.

Comment: @SethJ, my bad. I'll clarify what I'm asking about.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to ask whether he would violate the prohibition of idolatry, or the separate law of "martyr oneself rather than succumb"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rambam writes ([Yisodeh Hatorah 5:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=5&halocha=4&hilite=)):

> וכל מי שנאמר בו יהרג ואל יעבור ועבר ולא נהרג הרי זה מחלל את השם. ואם היה בעשרה מישראל הרי זה חילל את השם ברבים ובטל מצות עשה שהיא קידוש השם ועבר על מצות לא תעשה שהיא חלול השם. ואעפ"כ מפני שעבר באונס אין מלקין אותו ואין צריך לומר שאין ממיתין אותו בית דין אפילו הרג באונס
>
> Whatever circumstance that requires to be killed and not violate and he instead violated and was not killed he has profaned the Name. And if this was in front of 10 Jews, he profaned the Name publicly and failed to fulfill the positive commandment which is the sanctification of the Name and he violates the negative commandment of profaning the Name. Nevertheless since he violated it against his will, we do not give him lashes and needless to say we don't kill him in court even if he was forced to murder someone.

So someone is in violation of the commandment of martyrdom, but there is no earthly punishment.

Comment: This is but one side in a Machloket Rishonim, IIRC.

Comment: @DoubleAA, looks like someone agrees with you. Hopefully one of you will write up an answer with that information.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've been taught by many teachers, all of them Ashkenazim, who have cited this as authoritative. It could be that, since martyrdom scenarios have, sadly, been very relevant throughout Jewish history, whereas capital punishment meted out by Beith Din has not, most authorities (in my experience) seem to accept the RaMBa"M's view (possibly as a way of not further frightening/worrying a terrorized community), although some have taken (at least academic) license to be strict.

Comment: @Yishai My notes say a Tosfot in Sanhedrin and the Yereim disagree. I can't spend much more time on this for now.

Comment: @SethJ Why was anyone teaching you whether or not someone gets punished in these cases? There is no punishment nowadays. I don't follow your comment.

Comment: I believe Rambam here was defending the Jews who were forced by Muslims to convert at swordpoint.

Comment: @Seth J  - absolutely it has historical relevance - I remember reading that this is part of what inspired thr creation of Kol Nidre - possibly in a Siddur commentary.

Comment: @Gary, are you commenting on my comment, or answering on my behalf to DoubleAA's comment?

Comment: And @GregoryMagarshak. Learning Halachah is part of what we do.  I am confused by your confusion, Double AA.

Comment: @SethJ In many halacha classes you learnt about whether or not Beit Din would mete out punishment if you violated a big-three with witness and warning under pain of death? That's bizarre.

Comment: @DoubleAA, you're being too literalist with my words. If I must clarify my words for someone of your JLLy and English experience, either I have failed to communicate properly or you have deliberately refused to interpret my words as they were intended. I lean towards the latter here. But for the sake of, heck, no reason I can think of really, I will try to explain: I have attended many Torah classes, delving into Halachah about YeHareg VeAl Ya'Avor, either as the primary subject or a secondary point, that have cited RaMBa"M's opinion and indicated that it is authoritative.

Comment: @SethJ I don't know what's confusing you about my response. I still find that bizarre that anyone would indicate whether it's authoritative on this matter.

Comment: @Yishai It's the second opinion Tosfot Shabbat 72a and see Tosfot AZ 54a, but the Rama does quote your Rambam in 157:1 and it seems to me that Rov Rishonim support it (eg. Chinukh 295, Rivash 4 about Edut).

Comment: @Seth J - yours! You mentioned martyrdom scenarios-I am but a Talmud minnow, so I can't comment knowledgeably on Double AA's comment.

Comment: @Gary, well I think we agree. If you're a Talmud minnow, I don't know where that places me, but I feel like, maybe, a Talmud goldfish to Double AA's Talmud tuna.

Comment: @SethJ Perhaps a [tanna tuna](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90+%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90%22) (pictured [here](https://img1.etsystatic.com/003/0/7128016/il_570xN.364923829_nv0k.jpg))?